# is it possible to assign a function to another function in typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to set current function to null loop in typescript, this is my code looks like:

```
export function noop() {}

export function removeFirstMouseUp() {
  removeFirstMouseUp = noop;
}
```

but the compiler told me this error:

```
 TS2630: Cannot assign to 'removeFirstMouseUp' because it is a function.
```

assign a function to another function, it seems no problem. why the typescript compiler shows this error? what did I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of defining `removeFirstMouseUp` as a function declaration, rewrite it as a function definition:

```js
export function noop() {}

export let removeFirstMouseUp = function() {
    removeFirstMouseUp = noop;
}
```

From ESLint's [no-func-assign](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-func-assign) page:

> JavaScript functions can be written as a FunctionDeclaration function foo() { ... } or as a FunctionExpression var foo = function() { ... };. While a JavaScript interpreter might tolerate it, overwriting/reassigning a function written as a FunctionDeclaration is often indicative of a mistake or issue.

ESLint and TypeScript are different, however, in this case the error messages are referring to [the same thing](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/983).

Answer (score 2):

You can only change a function expression and not a function declaration. If you store a function expression in a variable and return it from an exported function then you can change it.

```js
const noop = () => {}

const firstMouseUp = () => {
}

let func = firstMouseUp;

export function getFunc () {
  return func;
}

export function removeFirstMouseUp() {
  func = noop;
}
```

Play [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&module=100&noImplicitOverride=true&noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBGIgA4wLwwBQEpUD4YG8BfAWACgzRJYAzASwCdoBZEAVwgFMBVZNLXAmRLlSAGw41WYYKhh1GUFu26IA3GTIcAHohD1J0qLXAwA5hIBiUmf3xkYMehNb0wc6%20tLDNOvQeBGJk4AtiAAbhwWDMxsnDy29u7SsvBInoRAA)

Answer (score 1):

It would seem you are just looking for

```
export function noop() {}

export function removeFirstMouseUp() {
  return(noop);
}
```