# Why can't I reassign a function in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, function

Reassigning a function in vanilla JavaScript is perfectly fine code...

```js
function f() {}

f = function() {}
```

..., but when I do this with TypeScript I get a compiler error telling me this is not allowed?! ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAFASkQbwL4ChiIC8y408S6W2A3LkA))

```
function f() {}

f = function () {}; /*
~ Cannot assign to 'f' because it is a function. */
```

So I was wondering what the particular reason is that this feature seems to be forbidden. I know that this works with [function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) (See [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAZhC8EAoCUcB8EDeBfA3AKBnmTU1zyA)) but not with function declarations. I couldn't find anything helpful in the [TypeScript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-type-expressions) nor anywhere else.

Please note, that I'm not interested in a workaround but an actual explanation for this behavior.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript: Re-assigning a function with another function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019849/javascript-re-assigning-a-function-with-another-function)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70982314/17709311

Comment: Your use of the phrase "perfectly fine" to describe something that [is generally discouraged](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function#description) reminds me of [this question and its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41750390/2887218).  I don't think it's explicitly documented anywhere, although it's clear from the compiler code that it is intended to be an error (hard to link that huge file here).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Does that mean the only reason it shows an error is because in JavaScript it is something that *should be avoided*? There are plenty of JS anti patterns but I don‘t understand why TypeScript should prevent them with errors. If thats the case I would love to see an answer.

Comment: Eh I wrote an answer but unless there’s a GitHub issue where this exact topic was discussed it’s hard to say authoritatively *why* some language property is the way it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caveat: I don't know if this constitutes an objectively correct answer to "why doesn't TypeScript allow reassignments of functions declared via function statement?"  To be sure, I'd have to find some authoritative documentation or official statement that provides the reasoning behind this particular prohibition, and I have not found one so far.  Therefore what follows is just an educated guess given such statements about other situations.

---

It's not one of the design goals TypeScript to allow all valid JavaScript to compile in TypeScript without issuing compiler errors (although it *is* one of the design goals that even with such errors, the code will be compiled and *emitted* as JavaScript).  The litmus test for issuing a compiler error is not "will this cause a runtime error in JavaScript" but "is this likely to be a coding mistake".  See [What does "all legal JavaScript is legal TypeScript" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41750390/2887218) and its answer for an authoritative source.

For examples of this, see:

- [microsoft/TypeScript#17203](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17203), a declined suggestion to allow [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) to allow non-`string` inputs
- [microsoft/TypeScript#22821](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22821), a declined suggestion to allow calling [the `split()` method of `string`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) without an argument
- [microsoft/TypeScript#49766](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49766), a declined suggestion to allow passing a `null` `space` argument to [the `JSON.stringify()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).
- [microsoft/TypeScript#55083](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/55083), a declined suggestion to allow [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals) non-objects into an object literal.

In all of those cases JavaScript allows something and there is a well-defined outcome, but TypeScript takes the position that it's a mistake to do it.

So it might be true that "reassigning a function in vanilla JavaScript is perfectly fine code", but that doesn't necessarily imply that it should be perfectly fine *TypeScript* code.

Note that I'm not trying to say that I personally agree with the decisions in all the above cases or in this case.  There have definitely been times when I disagree with the TS team's decision on allowing or prohibiting certain coding techniques, and usually it comes down to a difference in priorities for supporting certain use cases.  If I think some use case is more important than the TS team does, then I might be unhappy when the language doesn't have an affordance for it.  Conversely if I think there's a major safety hole in the language but the TS team cares about some use case that the hole enables, I might be unhappy when the language is unsound.  These ultimately come down to a combination of real world code statistics, compiler performance, and the subjective opinions of the TS language's maintainers.

---

The likely reason why `function`-statement-declared functions cannot be reassigned in TypeScript is that the TS team thinks it's probably a mistake to do it.

[MDN's documentation for `function` statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function#description) [currently](https://github.com/mdn/content/blob/58c049a082830160aef24e3eb11494c54045b67e/files/en-us/web/javascript/reference/statements/function/index.md#L48) says "function declarations can be re-assigned, but you should avoid doing so".  I don't know if we can take MDN as authoritative here or not, but it's at least one data point.

Generally speaking it would be unfortunate if something like

```
parseFloat = x => 0
```

were allowed with no error, right?  Unless TypeScript introduced the concept of a `readonly` function declaration and marked every single native JS function as being one, we're mostly left with the two extremes "allow all function reassignments (whose types match)" or "prohibit all function reassignments", and TS has opted for the latter.

When I look at the too-large-for-GitHub's-UI [`checker.ts` file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/TypeScript/v5.2.2/src/compiler/checker.ts), at approximately line 28,031, I see

```
if (assignmentKind) {
  if (!(localOrExportSymbol.flags & SymbolFlags.Variable) &&
    !(isInJSFile(node) && localOrExportSymbol.flags & SymbolFlags.ValueModule)) {
    const assignmentError = localOrExportSymbol.flags & SymbolFlags.Enum ? Diagnostics.Cannot_assign_to_0_because_it_is_an_enum
      : localOrExportSymbol.flags & SymbolFlags.Class ? Diagnostics.Cannot_assign_to_0_because_it_is_a_class
      : localOrExportSymbol.flags & SymbolFlags.Module ? Diagnostics.Cannot_assign_to_0_because_it_is_a_namespace
      : localOrExportSymbol.flags & SymbolFlags.Function ? Diagnostics.Cannot_assign_to_0_because_it_is_a_function
      : localOrExportSymbol.flags & SymbolFlags.Alias ? Diagnostics.Cannot_assign_to_0_because_it_is_an_import
      : Diagnostics.Cannot_assign_to_0_because_it_is_not_a_variable;
```

so TypeScript takes the position that reassigning to a `function` statement is the same class of mistake as reassigning a `class` statement or a `module`.  That is, it's like a category error. You're not intended to clobber these things.

---

So there you go.  All I know for a fact is that it's disallowed in TypeScript and that in other cases where TypeScript disallows valid JavaScript it's because the TS team considers such code to be a likely error.  The same is probably true here, and there is circumstantial evidence of that.